# Is it possible to extend an enum in graphql

Tags: enums, graphql, graphql-js

I have one enum:

```
enum Content {
  QUESTION
  SOLUTION
}
```

Can this enum be extended like (In Node):

```
extend enum Content {
  QUESTION @external
  SOLUTION @external
  ANSWER
}
```

Comment: What is the case behind this?

Answer (score 2):

It is allowed by the specification, see https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Enum-Extensions

From the use of the `external` directive, I imagine you would want to use it in a federated gateway. I am not confident this will work considering the wording of the Apollo documentation: [`For enums and unions, all possible values must match across all defining subgraphs`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/value-types/#enums-and-unions). I would suggest you use a shared package to create the shared types instead so the schema composition doesn't fail.

Comment: This has since been updated, and they are not always required to match across all subgraphs. They must only match if the enum is used as both a return value and an input type. Otherwise, it is unioned if it is a return value and intersected if it is an input type. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/federated-types/composition#enums